# Create a new test using other test in groovy with geb and spock

Tags: grails, testing, groovy, spock, geb

I have created one test to buy a ticket in my webpage BuyTicketSpec.groovy.

```
  class BuyTicketsSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def (String country, String userType, String type, String payment, String env) {

    }
}
```

I have created others tests to modify ModifyTicketSpec o delete a ticket DeleteTicketSpec.

Could I create a geb test to combine this test in one?  For example FullCycleTicket.groovy test where i try to buy, modify and delete a ticket.

```
      class FullCycleTicketsSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

        def (String country, String userType, String type, String payment, String env) {

setup:
//initialize

when:
//launch BuyTicketSpec
//launch ModifyTicketSpec
//launch DeleteTicketSpec

then:
//

where:

        }
    }
```

Is it possible using geb and spock framework?

I appreciate your help. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As erdi said, traits can be very useful when it comes to reusing common code.

Simple example:

```
class TestBasicStuff extends GebReportingSpec implements StuffMeister {
    def 'do some basic stuff'() {
        someBasicStuff()
    }
}

class TestNotOnlyBasicStuff extends GebReportingSpec implements StuffMeister {
    def 'do not only basic stuff'() {
        someBasicStuff()
        someAdvancedStuff()
    }
}

trait StuffMeister {
    def someBasicStuff() { 'basic' }
    def someAdvancedStuff() { 'not basic' }
}
```

Comment: Thank you aMoosingOne to give a example how i have to use. I apreciatte you help!!

Answer (score 2):

Extract common code to another class or trait and call methods on that class from your specs (both the `FullCycleSpec` and "partial" specs like `BuyTicketSpec`).

I would not try to reuse specs because specs have a lifecycle and it's the testing framework that will execute them. That's why you're better of having common code in a non spec class.

Comment: Ok. I will try this comment to do a test core to use in different Spec. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you cannot sequence a series of when: / then: pairs to test all the way through your process flow. I don't believe you can just make calls out to other spec's though.

```
setup:
    // initialize

when:
    // buy ticket spec when code

then:
    // buy ticket spec then code

when:
    // modify ticket spec when code

then:
    // etc...
```

Comment: Thanks you, but my idea is reused other test to avoid copy/paste code. If i have to change my "buyTicket" test to add new funtionality and use in different case (buy - modify, buy-delete, buy 10 ticket and manage them in a table and test this table), the solution is to change my "buyTicket" test not to repeat X times the same code in other test where i want yo buy a ticket. English is not my natural language. If you have some doubt, ask me.